# Десериализация объекта в С#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, сериализация

Имеется объект настроек **EntityFramework**, содержащий строки подключения (**Properties.Settings.Default**). Нужно изменить каждую имеющуюся там строку подключения.

Ни перебором элементов, ни с помощью индексатора проблема не решилась, т.к. чтобы установить строе подключения значение нужно указать Properties.Settings.Default["имя подключения"]. Список строк подключения находится в файле App.copnfig, но прочитать их оттуда не удается. Поэтому я посмотрел в сторону десерриализации. Подскажите, как правильно десереализовать объекты? Куча инфы найдена,  но толку мало, т.к. почти всегда имеется файлик с сериализованным объектом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[_connectionStringName].ConnectionString = textBox1.Text;
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

Оригинал на http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/b865ce7a-6616-4109-90a5-553efc928075/modify-connectionstring-in-appconfig